# how to split delimited space and trim in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, split, delimiter

I'm Trying to split delimited space and trim in vb.net.

Please Guide Me

Thanks

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
Dim s As String = "     5010    2024-03-18 06:59:10 1   0   0   0"
Dim words As String() = s.Split(CType(vbTab, Char()))
 For Each word As String In words
            Console.WriteLine("WORD: {0}", word)
        Next
        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

output from above code

```
WORD:      5010
WORD: 2024-03-18 06:59:10
WORD: 1
WORD: 0
WORD: 0
WORD: 0
```

desired output

```
WORD: 5010
WORD: 2024-03-18
WORD: 06:59:10
WORD: 1
WORD: 0
WORD: 0
WORD: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried word.Trim()? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-8.0#system-string-trim

Comment: @AlekDavis , Thanks. for trim solved `Console.WriteLine("WORD: {0}", word.Trim())` but  for this from `WORD: 2024-03-18 06:59:10` to `WORD: 2024-03-18` `WORD: 06:59:10` for this is not yet solved

Comment: I posted a comment your previous question and suggested that you use a `TextFieldParser`. You have tagged this question with that class but you have made absolutely no effort to actually use it. I even provided you with a link to the class documentation and told you that it included a code example but you've made no effort to even look at it, as far as I can tell. Don't lie to people. Either make an effort to use a `TextFieldParser` or else don't apply the irrelevant tag to your question. As it is irrelevant right now, I have removed it.

Comment: Maybe this help: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-8.0#system-string-split(system-char())` Examples

Comment: @Blackcat , 
Thank you for your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

according to recommendations from @Blackcat

and based on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-8.0#system-string-split(system-char())

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
Dim s As String = "     5010    2024-03-18 06:59:10 1   0   0   0"
Dim separators As Char() = New Char() {" "c, Char.Parse(vbTab)}
        Dim words As String() = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
For Each word As String In words
            Console.WriteLine("WORD: {0}", word)
        Next
        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Output Result

```
WORD: 5010
WORD: 2024-03-18
WORD: 06:59:10
WORD: 1
WORD: 0
WORD: 0
WORD: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One more.  When I copied and pasted original code the tabs were scrubbed, or they were scrubbed when posted.

```
    Dim s As String = " 5010    2024-03-18  06:59:10    1   0   0   0"
    Dim splts() As Char = {ControlChars.Tab, " "c}
    Dim words() As String = (From foo In s.Split(splts, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) Select foo.Trim).ToArray
    For Each word As String In words
        Console.WriteLine("WORD: {0}", word)
    Next
    Console.Read()
```